# I get Error while working with Fetch and FlatList but Code is working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey Guys im working with fetch and want to display the Information in a Flatlist.
It works as it should be but VSCode keeps giving me Errors saying :"The "quote" property is not present for the "never" type."
Can I just ignore this Error?

```
const movieURL = "https://dummyjson.com/quotes";

export default function App() {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
console.log(data);

const getMoviesFromApi = () => {
    fetch(movieURL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json.quotes))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
};

useEffect(() => {
    getMoviesFromApi();
}, []);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Text>
                    {" "}
                    {item.quote}, {item.author}
                </Text>
            )}
        />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />`
    </View>
);
```

}

Comment: seems to be a TS err 

Comment: What is a "TS Error"?
And can i ignore that?
Ty for your answer.

Comment: `TypeScript` .. not sure

Comment: I searched and check if it works if you replace - `{item.quote}, {item.author}` to `{item["quote"]}, {item["author"]}`

Comment: Thank you very much thats the solution! :)